# jQuery set css left to value 1 and after done to value 2?

Tags: jquery, css, queue

I am just curious about how to achieve the following:

I have created a simple slider, automatically sliding to the left. The slides are arranged like 1st `0% left`, 2nd `100% left`, 3rd `200% left` on initial load. They automatically slide to the left.

So after the first move the left values read like 1st `-100%`, 2nd `0%`, 3rd `100%`. With the next move the element having `left -100%` is getting `left 200%` in the 3 slide example.

Now I implemented move left/ move right buttons. While the move left button works easy, I have massive problems with the move right button.

The issue:

Once there is no slide having css `left -100%`, the most right slide needs to be brought into that position. In the example the slide having css `left 200%` needs to be set to `-100%` and after the position changed, it should be set to `0%`.

The problem:

Css `left -100%` is not set (the slide does not move from `left 200%` to `-100%` and then to `0%`, but directly from `200%` to `0%`).

I used `queue`, but this doesn't work anyhow and I am clueless now.

In the function I first run `each()` to identify the element which has the highest left value. Then I run `each()` again to make them move. Its all fine, except for the problem above.

How can I achieve my goal?

```
function moveSlidesReverse() {
var slides = jQuery('#main').children('.dfmn-section-slider');
var pos2 = 0;

slides.each(function() {
    pos = jQuery(this)[0].style.left;
    pos = parseInt(pos.substring(0,pos.indexOf('%')));
    if (pos == -100) {
        outerSlide = '';
        return false;
    } else if (pos > pos2) {
        pos2 = pos;
        outerSlide = jQuery(this).attr('id');
    } 
});
slides.each(function() {
    pos = jQuery(this)[0].style.left;
    pos = parseInt(pos.substring(0,pos.indexOf('%')));
    if (outerSlide != jQuery(this).attr('id')) {
        jQuery(this).removeClass('dfmn-section-slider-static')
                .addClass('dfmn-section-slider-animate')
                .css('left', (pos+100) + '%');
    } else  {
        jQuery(this).removeClass('dfmn-section-slider-animate')
                .addClass('dfmn-section-slider-static')
                .css('left', '-100%')
                .queue(function() {
                jQuery(this).removeClass('dfmn-section-slider-static')
                        .addClass('dfmn-section-slider-animate')
                        .css('left', '0%')
                        .dequeue;
                });     
    }
});
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a "setInterval" function to make the slider move by it self.
Then I would STOP the interval on the "MouseEnter" events of the gallery (use "clearInterval"), then finally I would use "one" function to activate the arrows.

Note that using "one" you should bind the event at the very end of the animation; something like this:

```
$('.NAME').one('click',function(){ "MOVE-YOUR-GALLERY";})

function MOVE-YOUR-GALLERY(){
        $(.gallery).animate({....}, 5000, function(){
        $('.NAME').one('click',function(){ "MOVE-YOUR-GALLERY";})
    } )
}
```

Comment: Thanks for Your input. I already use setInterval to make the slider move by itself. Your further input did not answer my question, but helped anyways. I replaced the line `.css('left', '-100%')` with `.animate({left: '-100%'}, 0)`. Obviously `.css` isn't in the FX-queue.

Comment: @ThommyTomka unless you preset the animation rule in css and Move it with JS.